# Must remove node_modules every time i install a package

Tags: node.js, electron, package.json

I've updated node to 8.1.x (and npm) while using it with Electron (atom Shell) to build an app.

Right now it creates a new package-lock.json file, and every time i install a new library i have to tear down the whole node_modules folder, or  a bunch of error message of "library not found" shows up, even if is in the package dependencies list.

what's going on?!

Comment: NodeJs 8.1.0 has a very mean bug that breaks a lot of functions, please be sure to install 8.1.2.

Other than that could you provide you package.json, or at least the dependcies ?

Comment: I got node 8.1.2